Can I retreive an original matrix from its Pearson correlation counterpart?
I was wondering if this problem can be solved or not.
Let us assume that I have a squared matrix that is symmetric and contains only non-negative values. In addition, that matrix is doubly stochastic.
From that matrix, I get a Pearson correlation matrix between all rows and columns.
If I observe this last correlation matrix and know the above constraints, can I estimate back the original matrix?
This question is similar to what is asked here: Going back from a correlation matrix to the original matrix But I think that the additional constraints might change the answer.

A scalar multiple of a matrix will have the same correlation matrix.

But its rows/columns would not sum to 1, right? The original matrix is doubly stochastic
